# Oracle 19c scheduling jobs 14 hours in the future when using DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

We've got a client who's recently migrated to Oracle 19c on an AWS. Since the migration, any Oracle jobs that are created within our application, using DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT, are scheduled to run 7 hours ahead of the DB server time.

For example, the following test code was run on a client's machine at 7:00. The time on the AWS server was 14:00 but the actual job was created to run at 21:00

```
DECLARE
  I NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(I, 'DECLARE I NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(1) INTO I FROM DUAL; END;');
  COMMIT;
END;
```

This sounds time zone related? Any thoughts?

Update:

Our clients are based in the US (I'm in the UK) and when I run the code above on their DB, with my OS Time zone set to "(UTC+00:00) London", the job is scheduled immediately. If I update my OS Time Zone to "(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time", to mimic their OS, running the code above schedules the job to run in 7 hours time.

Comment: You've tagged this for 19c-- dbms_job was depricated in 19c for dbms_scheduler.  Does dbms_scheduler work correctly?  Does `dbms_job.submit` work correctly when you explicitly specify `sysdate`?  What do `sysdate` and `systimestamp` return as the current time?

Comment: `SYSDATE` returns the current date and time set for the operating system on which the database server resides. `CURRENT_DATE` returns the current date in the session time zone. Compare the values returned by these functions to wall time and workstation time wherever you are and perhaps you'll discover some unexpected values.

Comment: We have the same problem. Could you find any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by a bug that I have just nailed down. I have created a service request at Oracle, so they can fix this in their code of dbms_ijob. Looks like it this bug has been introduced in 19c where the dbms_job code has been refactored to just be a facade to dbms_scheduler. The bug still exists in the latest Oracle DB RU, i.e., 19.19. The dbms_ijob package does a wrong conversion from date to timestamp where it interprets the current database hosts system time (sysdate) as a time in the timezone of the current session (while it is a time in the timezone of the database host os). This leads to the seen offset. This offset can be positive and negative, which leads to a too early or too late start of the job. Only workaround right now is to switch to dbms_scheduler or to offset the dbms_job.submit next_date parameter to compensate the wrong timestamp.

Comment: Can you please share Oracle support request number or link?

Comment: As soon as a bug is created or associated from my service request, I will post the bug number.

Comment: Bug has just been created at Oracle, but it looks like it is not yet public: Bug 35378061 - DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT CREATED JOBS DELAY